# Second Order differential equation with $|y'|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you guys help me solve this differential equation:

$$y''+|y'|~y'+y=K \sin x$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, it's meant to be abs(y')*y'

Comment: Because $y$ is a function, I'm not sure the trick of considering positive and negative $y'$ separately will work. Anyway, non-linear second-order, not sure there's a solution. Wolfram isn't happy about it. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+abs%28y%27%29*y%27+%2B+y+%3D+sin%28x%29